# Pass value from one class to another

Tags: android

I have 3 classes:

- `AddText`(extends Activity)
- `Grafitti`(extends MapActivity)
- `MarkerOverlay`

`Grafitti` calls `AddText`, and `AddText` opens a new Activity that gets an input from user (EditText), then when that is successful `Grafitti` calls `MarkerOverlay`.

The problem is I can't access the input in `AddText`. I need to use that input in `MarkerOverlay`, I tried creating a setter and getter but it won't work. (error)

I've tried searching the web and I think the solution is Bundle. I'm having a hard time understanding how Bundle works. Is there any other way? or any code snippet on how to use Bundle.  A code snippet would really help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Grafitti needs to start AddText via `startActivityForResult()` and then listen for the result via `onActivityResult()`.

For more info see this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities